# Angular redirect for blocked route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I want to block certain routes when a user has not accepted an agreement, etc.  Using `$locationChangeStart` works pretty well:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newVal, oldVal) {        
    var targetPage = newVal.substring(newVal.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    if (!acceptedRelease && targetPage != "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $location.path("/");
    }
});
```

This works fine as long as the initial page is loaded with the route `/` (i.e. empty).  However, if you load the page with `/mainMenu` or the like, it does not work.  The route itself is blocked via `event.preventDefault()`, but `$location.path` does not fire/redirect appropriately.  Using

```
$scope.$apply(function () { $location.path("/"); })
```

does not work either.  I get an error `$digest already in progress`.

Is there any way to redirect after blocking a route in `$locationChangeStart`?

In general, is there any way to block certain routes in Angular and perform redirects when the routes have been blocked?

Comment: `$routChange` events might be better...this blog might help  http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app. Accepted release could be swapped for `logged in` so principles would be same

Comment: @Explosion Pills, I'm encountering the same problem, wondering if and how you solved this in the end?

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this in you routeChangeSuccess:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(){
    if(!acceptedTermsVar){
      $location.path('/wherever-you-want');
    }
});
```